# I am unable to see any wifi networks

Tags: networking

Turning wifi on and connecting to hub not possible.

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
Running KDE
```

Hi Folks

Two weeks ago BT changed my hub to Fibre.

Two weeks of plestering on the linux machine and on the internet with android machine, (mt only internet souroe), I have not moved forward one inch.

The nclmi cmmd has provided me with information but I'm not knowledgable enough to either use it or modify it without express instructions.

I shall try to attach a photo of the nclmi output if I can and perhaps you could give me guidance,

FOR information, the hub identity is shown, so a wifi link must exist.

Thanks
Chris

ADDENDUM

nclmi output has this line:

```
NAME UUID TYPE DEVICE
lxcbr0 d32cde etc bridge lxcbr0 
BT-JCXXXX 5acoce etc wifi --
```

The `BT-JCxx` is my hub.

Comment: If your details are correct (*which show 20.04.1; alas not where that detail was from*), you've not applied security fixes & updates in years, as [this](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/02/05/ubuntu-20-04-2-lts-released/) shows the ISO release of 20.04.2, but installed systems upgraded **before** that date. Are you using Ubuntu? as I'll suggest applying security fixes asap  (your details may match a non-Ubuntu system that is Ubuntu-based; but your system maybe rather insecure if you're still using 20.04.1 as your release; unless 20.04.1 is packaging detail only).  Upgrade asap!